# Converting a binary number to decimal from a file with whitespace

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to convert binary numbers to decimal from a file. I am able to get the numbers to convert, however, in my text file, if I have more then one binary number in a line the code just skips it.

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    File file = new File("binary.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String text = null;
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
            try {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(text,2));
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the text file that I am using as well:

```
00100101
00100110 01000001
01100000
01111011
10010100 00100101
01101011
11000111 00011010
```

When I run my code I get: [37, 96, 123, 107]
The code skips the lines where there are two binary numbers.
I'm having trouble trying to be able to convert the integers and not use reader.readLine() in the while loop. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `catch (Exception ex) { continue; }` is why the code "just skips it" (and silently too, very bad).

Comment: Why don't you just read the file char by char?

Answer (score 1):

Split each line read by the `while` loop using [`text.split("\\s+")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), and iterate the split values:

```
String text = null;
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    for (String value : text.split("\\s+")) {
        try {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(value,2));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            continue; // should throw error: File is corrupt
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do for when you have multiple values in one line.

You loop over the multiple values and add them separately.

```
try {
    for (String s : text.split(" ") list.add(Integer.parseInt(s,2));
}
```

Also, like Andreas wrote it, it is not recommended to ignore Exceptions.